# undefined value from ajax success response using json data

Tags: php, json, curl

My CURL code is as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://my ip address/api/FeedbackCustomerDetails?accessKey=$access_key&AccountNo=$subscriber_code");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);                                                                                                                  
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$response = print stripslashes(json_encode($result));
```

The response from my curl is as follows:

```
"{"CENTER":"BRADFORD","STATUS":"0","SUB_NAME":"PETER ","ACCOUNT_NO":"HB92008117","ASSOCIATE_ID":"850N027","STATUS_TEXT":"SUCCESS","REGION":"UK"}"
```

Without **strip_slashes** the output is:

```
"{\"CENTER\":\"BRADFORD\",\"STATUS\":\"0\",\"SUB_NAME\":\"PETER \",\"ACCOUNT_NO\":\"HB92008117\",\"ASSOCIATE_ID\":\"850N027\",\"STATUS_TEXT\":\"SUCCESS\",\"REGION\":\"UK\"}"
```

I tried the following and always get "undefined"

```
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.ACCOUNT_NO);
},
```

I need to display the data in a span id. I tried the following too:

```
$("#subscriber code").text(response[0].ACCOUNT_NO);
```

**response.ACCOUNT_NO;** always results in **UNDEFINED**.

What am i doing wrong?? Requesting help..

Comment: its possible the JSON integrity will be lost after the strip slashes, so try `json_decode()` and then `json_encode()`

Comment: Okay, so i tried:
$response = json_decode($result, true);
$response = print json_encode($response);

Comment: But alert(response.ACCOUNT_NO); is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to JSON.parse() the result first?
You have an "undefined" value of this property, because your response is a string, not an object. And string do not have property named "ACCOUNT_NO".
You should parse your response into object first.

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
alert( response.ACCOUNT_NO );
```

Comment: Thank you. After json_decode() and then json_encode() as recommended by @jidexl21 and JSON.parse it worked fine.

Comment: if you don't want to have to `JSON.parse` your response all the time, use `header("Content-type:application/json");` before sending the output.